# HTML and Typescript buttons without React?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

**UPDATED CODE (still not working)** I have been trying to figure out why my buttons weren't working on the html, and all of the tutorials I see use React or Angular. I was wondering if there is a way for my code to run without it.

This is the simplest I've gotten it down to and none of the examples I've been following have made it run.
Currently it's **just a button that gives an alert**, and I just need help to figure out how to get that small part to work

**edits:**
transpiled from .ts to .js,
changed the forgotBtn to same as eventListener

> This is my HTML Code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Capstone Typescript Login</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<header>
    <h2>Billy Bronco's Grading Calculator</h2>
</header>

<div id="container">

    <div id="tabs">

        <p id="lt" class="tabs" onclick="loginTabFun()">Log in</p>
        <p id="rt" class="tabs" onclick="regTabFun()">Register</p>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Login.css">

        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="cont">

        <div id="login" class="comm">
            <h3>Sign in</h3>

            <input id="se" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
            <input id="sp" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>

            <input type="button" class="button" id="enter" value="Login">
            <input type="button" class="button" id="forgotPass" value="Forgot Password?">

        </div>


        <div id="register" class="comm">
            <h3>Register</h3>

            <input id="re" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
            <input id="rp" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
            <input id="rrp" type="password" placeholder="Re write Password" required/>
            <input type="submit" onclick="register()" value="Submit"/>

        </div >


        <div id="forgot" class="comm">
            <h3>Forgot Password</h3>
            <div>
                <input id="fe" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
                <input type="submit" onclick="forgot()" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<script src="LoginTs.js"></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

> and this is my Typescript code:

```
class LoginTs{
    username: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(username: string, password: string ) {
        this.username=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("se")).value;
        this.password=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("sp")).value;
        

        let submitBtn= document.getElementById("enter")
        submitBtn.addEventListener("click",(e:Event) =>{ return loginTs.validateInput()});

        let forgotBtn= document.getElementById("forgotPass")
        forgotBtn.addEventListener("click",(e:Event) =>loginTs.validateInput());
    }

    validateInput(){
             return alert("wrong user or password but good job erin")
    }

let loginTs = new LoginTs("billy", "bronco");
loginTs.validateInput();
```

> Thank You!

Comment: Typescript does not run natively on the browser. You must use javascript or use a compiler to transpile your Typescript into Javascript. So your file `<script src="LoginTs.ts"></script>` will not be parsed correctly.

Comment: Like @martin66 said Typescript is not something the browser understands, but it's possible to use Typescript in the browser without having to transpile beforehand by using -> https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what jQuery did that made it so popular - until the DOM is built your JS won't be able to find anything. You want the hooking up of events to happen after the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event.

You also have a .ts file in your script tag, but you need the transpiled .js file for the browser. Change this to:

```html
<script src="LoginTs.js"></script>
```

`LoginTs.js` is the default, or set wherever your `tsconfig.json` sets your output to.

Then your DOM queries don't match your HTML:

```html
<input id="se" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
<input id="sp" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
```

```
this.username=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("email")).value;                      
this.password=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("password")).value;
```

Change this to:

```
this.username=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("se")).value;                      
this.password=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("sp")).value;
```

Next up you're trying to call `onclick="validateInput()"` on the forgot button but the method is an instance on `loginTs` declared with a `let` in a script file - you're best off subscribing all your controls the same way and avoiding `onclick`, but if you want to reference your instance methods outside the script you either need to switch to `var loginTs` or set a global explicitly `window.loginTs`, and you need to include the reference to the instance (i.e. `loginTs.validateInput`).

Comment: I'm not sure they have a `tsconfig.js`

Comment: @Keith I was able to get it transpiled into .js and fixed the script tag, but the buttons still wont run for the alert :( is there something wrong possibly with my .ts code that wouldn't allow it to run? I'm not getting any errors and everything has compiled correctly.

Comment: @ErinB That's not all you need to do, I've expanded the question

Comment: thank you @Keith ! I have been able to make these changes (and I also updated my question) I still don't understand why the buttons aren't functioning. I was wondering if it could possibly be because of the constructor parameters? Or is there another syntax mistake that I don't understand? Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using babel or TS to compile your Typescript to a javascript output. You should then update your HTML from

```
<button onclick="validateInput()">Forgot Password?</button>
```

to

```
<button onclick="loginTs.validateInput()">Forgot Password?</button>
```

Your method validateInput lives within your class, and is therefore a class method. You need to prefix your method call with the class it belongs to. Which you set in the code:

```
let loginTs = new LoginTs("billy", "bronco");
```

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean by the "You need to prefix your method call with the class it belongs to. Which you set in the code:

let loginTs = new LoginTs("billy", "bronco"); "  (but dually noted on the login.Ts thank you)